# Do verbs following relative pronouns need to be in the past tense if the sentence begins in the subjunctive?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, subjunctive-mood, relative-pronouns

"I would prefer someone who was a bit more sincere about their beliefs."

vs.

"I would prefer someone who's a bit more sincere about their beliefs."

The second sounds more correct to me, since "someone who..." seems to be a single direct object.

However, when I replace "was" with another verb:

"I would prefer someone who cared about me."

vs.

"I would prefer someone who cares about me."

Both of these sound correct (though I suspect the first is technically correct, and the second perfectly fine in everyday vernacular).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking through relevant examples on the internet, I've found that my opinion that both past simple and present simple are acceptable here is bolstered. Even if it has been considered ungrammatical at some point in history, the simple present variant is surely becoming acceptable. But I can't find a reputable source to endorse my views.

Comment: I think it's just standard "backshifting" on a par with *He said he **was/is** English.* So there's no concept of "grammatically correct" here - it's a *stylistic choice*, where we *usually* backshift the verb in the subordinate clause to match initial ***would***. In which context I suggest neither ***would*** nor *someone who **was** X* actually have anything to do with "past time" as a concept - they both simply signify "not Present, not here-and-now" (usages primarily intended to convey "distance, politeness, hesitancy" here).